# Can't get a GET response in DJango Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to learn DJango Rest so I made a litte test to see if I could obtain some things from the database, but I'm getting some problems.

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

Here's my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Stock


class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ticker = serializers.CharField()
    open = serializers.FloatField()
    close = serializers.FloatField()
    volume = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Stock.objects.check(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.ticker = validated_data.get('ticker', instance.ticket)
        instance.open = validated_data.get('open', instance.open)
        instance.close = validated_data.get('close', instance.close)
        instance.volume = validated_data.get('volume', instance.volume)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .models import Stock
from .serializers import StockSerializer


# List all stocks or create a new one
# stocks/


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def stock_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stocks = Stock.objects.all()
        serializer = StockSerializer(stocks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = StockSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def stock_detail(request, pk, format=None):
    try:
        stock = Stock.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Stock.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = StockSerializer(stock)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = StockSerializer(stock, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        stock.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And finally, here's my url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from companies import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^stocks/', views.stock_list),
    url(r'^stocks/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.stock_detail),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I've been following  [this tutorial](http://from%20django.conf.urls%20import%20url%20from%20django.contrib%20import%20admin%20from%20rest_framework.urlpatterns%20import%20format_suffix_patterns%20from%20companies%20import%20views%20%20urlpatterns%20=%20[%20%20%20%20%20url(r'%5Eadmin/',%20admin.site.urls),%20%20%20%20%20url(r'%5Estocks/',%20views.stock_list),%20%20%20%20%20url(r'%5Estocks/(?P%3Cpk%3E[0-9]%20)$',%20views.stock_detail),%20]%20%20urlpatterns%20=%20format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)), but when it comes to the moment of making some requests (for this example I use this one: http http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/

I get this error message:

> TypeError at /stocks/ stock_list() missing 1 required positional
>   argument: 'request'

I think that the problem is with the urls, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Any ideas and some examples?

UPDATE: The problem was with the methods in view (they had an attibute self)

The general Get method works, but when I try to use POST 
POST ERROR:
When I try this request: http --form POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/ ticker='SAM'

I get this error:

> AttributeError at /stocks/ Got AttributeError when attempting to get a
>   value for field `ticker` on serializer `StockSerializer`. The
>   serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any
>   attribute or key on the `list` instance. Original exception text was:
>   'list' object has no attribute 'ticker'.

Comment: why do you want self argument in function?

Comment: That was the problem with the get requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove  `self`.

Remember you are using functions not clases.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def stock_list(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stocks = Stock.objects.all()
        serializer = StockSerializer(stocks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = StockSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: That was the problem for the get method! Thanks!But now I'm getting some errors when I try to POST and GET a single object.

Comment: when you are getting a single object you need send de `pk`,   `http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/1` , when `1` is the pk, and if the answer is correctly you should be mark this has answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Any idea why my POST method dosn't work?

Comment: Use Stock.objects.create(**validate_data)

Comment: Where should I put that?

Answer (score -1):

Try `views.stock_list.as_view()` in urls.py